# Passing Paramter to test method and running only specific method in testsuite

Tags: java, junit

Here is my test suite

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ LoginTest.class })
public class SmokeTestSuite {

}
```

Here is my LoginTest.class file

```
public class LoginTest extends MSTestBase {

    @Test
    public void User1LoginTest() throws Exception { 
        /*code*/
    }

    @Test
    public void User2LoginTest() throws Exception {         
        /*code*/
    }

    @Test
    public void User3LoginTest() throws Exception {         
        /*code*/
    }
}
```

I have 2 questions,

```
1- Can I run my SmokeTestSuite so it only execute User3LoginTest() method from LoginTest.class file?
2. Can I pass parameter to my Test Method from SmokeTestSuite file?
```